# Creating an array of dictionaries based on array elements in another column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

A row in an array column looks like this:

| old_params |
| --- |
| [a=1, b=2] |

I want to create a new array column of dictionaries based on params

| new_params |
| --- |
| [ {"name": "a", "value": 1},{"name": "b","value": 2} ] |

Is there any way of doing this, preferably without udfs. Thanks a lot in advance!

I somehow have to loop over array elements in params, split it by "=", and then add them to new_params' array with names & values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to loop over an array element and change them then `transform` function comes to mind.
I'm assuming your old_params is an array of strings and will use `split` to extract the name and value.
then finally `struct` is the function to create the dictionary-like object you are looking for.

I've also added an example how to read the values afterwards using `element_at` (as an example).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import transform, split, struct, element_at


df \
.withColumn(
    "new_params",
    transform(
        "old_params",
        lambda param: struct(
            split(param, "=")[0].alias("name"),
            split(param, "=")[1].alias("value")
        )
    )
) \
.withColumn("first_param_name", element_at("new_params", 1)['name'])

+----------+----------------+----------------+
|old_params|      new_params|first_param_name|
+----------+----------------+----------------+
|[a=1, b=2]|[{a, 1}, {b, 2}]|               a|
|[c=3, d=2]|[{c, 3}, {d, 2}]|               c|
+----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer, @walking, appreciate it! The code spits out exactly what you have described. But I would like to have:
[ {"name": "a", "value": 1},{"name": "b","value": 2} ], but not [{a, 1}, {b, 2}].

Furthermore wondering how you would handle if old_params had an empty list. Thank you again!

Comment: the code spits out exactly what you asked, it's a visualization issue with show. the struct has a {"name": "a", "value": 1} structure you can see in the `first_param_name` I've extracted the name by using ['name']
not sure about empty lists.